# Using Workbench to deploy destructive change set to eliminate apex class in production

Tags: change-set, workbench, destructivechanges.xml

I ran into an Apex Class error while trying to deploy a vendor package in Production from our partial Sandbox. The Apex class is obsolete and we have decided to delete it.

Not having any developer skills, but having some comfort level with workbench, I have opted to deploy a destructive change set in workbench as described [here](http://carvingintheclouds.blogspot.com/2013/12/deploying-destructive-changes-using.html).

I have followed the instructions exactly, but am concerned - the Metadata API Process status window has been running for an hour but still shows as Pending and shows NO Test errors and NO Tests Completed. The Auto refresh increases incrementally, so I know it is actively attempting the change.

What is my next step if it doesn't update or if it times out?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply login to SFDC and navigate to Setup -> Deploy -> Deployment Status

There you should see all the deployments Including those which are done using workbench.

There you can select the deployment and view status. If there are any issues it will report it there.

This is the deployment i did with workbench and its showing with proper status
[image: This is the deployment i did with workbench and its showing with proper status]

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't super comfortable with some of the Metadata API tooling then you could try one of the third parties that build services on top of it.

Full disclosure that I work for one of them [Gearset](https://gearset.com) but I'm only recommending it as it will solve your problem, and our free no-limits 30-day trial will mean you can use it to delete this class and not need to pay us anything :)

In the screenshot below, you can see I've done a comparison between two of my orgs and with a single checkbox can bring across the deletion. During the deployment, we'll give you full status reporting from the Metadata API.

[image: Deletion from Gearset]